# XAMPP Apache is starts and then suddenly stops

Tags: xampp

I have windown 7 and XAMPP version 3.0. As today I start the XAMPP and try to start Apache in the status panel it displays

```
Status change detected: running
Status change detected: stopped
```

I checked error.log but no error is there.

Comment: Do you have skype running on the same PC? if you have it:
http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Skype-XAMPP-problem/td-p/814106

Comment: No skype is not running on my PC

Answer (score 1):

1) go to config> apache (httpd.conf)

2) find "Listen 80" and change it to something like 8080 and save the file

3) click admin, it'll say "notfound"

4) in url after localhost write :8080 or the port number you wrote in httpd.conf

so it'll look like localhost:8080